# unable to load svg on canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I have a canvas here. And I'm trying to draw an svg on this but it just doesn't work at all. If I use a **png** file, it works as it should.

```
drawPlayer() {
    this.xCord = this.colNum * this.width;
    this.yCord = this.rowNum * this.height;

    let rat = new Image();
    let player = this;
        
    rat.onload = function() {player.ctx.drawImage(rat, player.xCord, player.yCord, 
        player.width, player.height);}
    rat.src = "Lik-Rong-IT.svg";
}
```

I also tried this way-

```
<img src="Lik-Rong-IT.svg" id="rat" style="display: none"/>
```

```
drawPlayer() {
    this.xCord = this.colNum * this.width;
    this.yCord = this.rowNum * this.height;

    let rat = document.querySelector("#rat");
    let player = this;

    rat.onload = function() {player.ctx.drawImage(rat, player.xCord, player.yCord, 
        player.width, player.height);}
}
```

But this also doesn't work (not even with png!). I've looked up for any mistake I could find in my code, but with no luck. Please help me find the issue!

link to project- https://codesandbox.io/s/maze-p2pyo

Comment: May you post the full code and/or the error message(if there's any)?

Comment: there's no error message. **png** file works but not svg. I've provided the codesandbox link in the question, although, live preview of canvas isn't working on codesandbox for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw an SVG on a canvas, one of the methods can be to first convert the **inline** SVG to Base 64 and then simply draw it on the canvas using `drawImage`. The only thing here is that the SVG should be **inline**.

Also, I forked your code and applied these changes and it seems to be working: https://codesandbox.io/s/maze-2wb5d

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const svg = new Image();

var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

// Convert it to base64
var svgBase64 = btoa(xml);
var imageBase64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + svgBase64;

svg.src = imageBase64;

svg.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(svg, 0, 0, 32, 32);
};
```

```css
svg {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M1,12C1,10.19 2.2,8.66 3.86,8.17C5.29,5.11 8.4,3 12,3C15.6,3 18.71,5.11 20.15,8.17C21.8,8.66 23,10.19 23,12C23,13.81 21.8,15.34 20.15,15.83C18.71,18.89 15.6,21 12,21C8.4,21 5.29,18.89 3.86,15.83C2.2,15.34 1,13.81 1,12M14.5,9.25A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 13.25,10.5A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 14.5,11.75A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 15.75,10.5A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 14.5,9.25M9.5,9.25A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 8.25,10.5A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 9.5,11.75A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 10.75,10.5A1.25,1.25 0 0,0 9.5,9.25M7.5,14C8.26,15.77 10,17 12,17C14,17 15.74,15.77 16.5,14H7.5M3,12C3,12.82 3.5,13.53 4.21,13.84C4.07,13.25 4,12.63 4,12C4,11.37 4.07,10.75 4.21,10.16C3.5,10.47 3,11.18 3,12M21,12C21,11.18 20.5,10.47 19.79,10.16C19.93,10.75 20,11.37 20,12C20,12.63 19.93,13.25 19.79,13.84C20.5,13.53 21,12.82 21,12Z" /></svg>

<canvas />
```

Comment: oh now I get it. even your method doesn't work (in firefox that I'm using). But my method and yours both work in ms edge! Do you know how can I fix it on firefox?

Comment: The thing with Firefox is that you have to specify the width and height of the SVG as it doesn't have an intrinsic size. I have arbitrarily set the width and height to 64px. Now this works on Firefox too: https://codesandbox.io/s/maze-2wb5d

Comment: I need to set width & height relative to current grid layout. But `rat.width = player.width` doesn't seem to work! Everything's working fine on Edge. Please help me with firefox!

Comment: Try to set width and height in a fixed ratio whichever suits. The image being drawn onto the canvas would take care of the variable dimensions I suppose.